# Run Selenide with Selenium 3.0.0?

Tags: java, selenium, firefox, dependencies, selenide

My Firefox is now v 48.  This doesn't appear to work with older versions of Selenium.  For that reason I had to change the (Gradle) Selenium dependency to

```
testCompile 'org.seleniumhq.selenium:selenium-java:3.+'
```

and then get hold of `geckodriver.exe` and change my Selenium test from:

```
WebDriver driver = new FirefoxDriver();
```

to

```
System.setProperty("webdriver.gecko.driver","D:\\apps\\geckodriver\\geckodriver-v0.10.0-win64\\geckodriver.exe");
DesiredCapabilities capabilities=DesiredCapabilities.firefox();
capabilities.setCapability("marionette", true);
WebDriver driver = new FirefoxDriver(capabilities);
```

(BTW, I haven't got a clue what all this Gecko, Marionette and Capabilties stuff is about... but the above works OK for Selenium)

But after cleaning the dependency cache, and instead using the latest version of Selenide, 3.9.1, the latter then puts Selenium 2.53 in the cache, and the following code:

```
    open("https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Main_Page");
```

... causes this error:

> Caused by: org.openqa.selenium.firefox.NotConnectedException: Unable
>   to connect to host 127.0.0.1 on port 7055 after 45000 ms. Firefox
>   console output:
>   -app-global","version":"1.0","type":"extension","internalName":null, ...

... which is, it appears, because Selenium 2.53 can't cope with my FF version.

I also tried using Selenium 3.0.0. with Selenide 3.9.1.  This didn't work either, which is not at all surprising, because presumably somewhere in the Selenide code it uses the following line:

```
WebDriver driver = new FirefoxDriver();
```

Any suggestions?  I don't want to use an older version of FF... that sort of technique is always unsatisfactory...  I suppose I might try fiddling with the relevant Selenide java file and recompiling... but what are people cleverer than me doing?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I just had an email from the author of Selenide who tells me this is a known problem and that the best thing is to use an old version of FF or, preferably, use Chrome.
I have gone with the latter solution and got my test passing.
I'm not **totally** happy with this because I have several reasons for disliking Chrome.  Hopefully a future version of Selenide will cater for newer FF versions.

Comment: I mention that it's not a problem of Selenide, but well-known Firefox webdriver problem. We all hope that future versions of Selenium webdriver will work with newer FF versions.